# Cannot connect to ssh from crontab

Tags: ssh

I can create ssh connection from the command line with this command(without password):

```
ssh -R 9900:localhost:22 user@host
```

I need to run this command whenever the system reboots, so I put it in a bash script and added this line to crontab:

```
@reboot /home/me/script.sh > output
```

But in output I get this error:
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhost: Name or service not known

I think it's because this script starts before internet connection is established. I put a `sleep(180)` before the ssh command, but it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this shouldn't be done using `cron`, this is what your init system is for. You could create a service that is dependent on your network state.

However, this should work if you are intent on using `cron`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

host="foo.bar.com"

# Wait for host's SSH server to become accessible
while ! ssh "user@$host" exit >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    sleep 1
fi

ssh -R 9900:localhost:22 "user@$host"
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work(I replaced then and fi with do and done).This one also works in command line, but not in cron

Comment: @user39463 Are you sure you can log in without a password? Did you set up your SSH agent properly?